# How did Andy bring down the authorities on the warden?

Tags: the-shawshank-redemption

At the close of *The Shawshank Redemption*, Andy flees the prison and the state authorities shortly arrive to arrest Captain Hadley and Warden Norton.

I understand that Andy had intimate knowledge of the corruption, violence and murder at Shawshank, but as a prisoner - and without proof - I struggle to see how he could have enough influence to provoke such a strong response from the authorities?

Comment: If you watch closely, he also takes the ledger that has all the actual records of the warden’s corruption with him when he escapes. Then when he goes to the bank, he says “could you put this in your outgoing mail?” It’s the ledger and a note that he’s sending to the newspaper.

Comment: To expand on comment by @ToddWilcox -  When he cleans out the bank account, he has a large mailing envelope that he asks them to send out in the mail.  Next scene, the envelope gets dropped on the desk of a newspaper reporter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because [a newspaper published the evidence](https://shawshank.fandom.com/wiki/Andy_Dufresne):

> He also mailed the evidence of their financial crimes to the Daily Bugle, presumably along with evidence of his own innocence. When the story was published, Captain Hadley was arrested and Warden Norton committed suicide to avoid arrest for his crimes.